# Adding a delay to npm's concurrently

Tags: npm, sass, scripting, aurelia, watch

I am using NPM's concurrently to run:

concurrently "npm run watch-sass" "npm run watch"

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "nps test",
    "watch-sass": "multi-sass -w -d static/css/pages -o static/css/pages -n -d static/css/common -o static/css/common -n -d static/css/components -o static/css/components",
    "watch": "nps webpack.build.development.watch",
    ...
  },
```

However, as soon as watch-sass completes a single file, watch runs and the files do not have a chance to be included in the build.

I need to insert some kind of delay after 'watch-sass' so that 'watch' will not activate until either (1) a delay everytime, or (2) a way to know when ALL scss files have been compiled.

Comment: you can use gulp to create a sewries of tasks, first you apply sass to all your files, and then you run `watch`. I see you have included `aurelia` as a tag - if you use the `cli` - take a look at the run/build task - this is how it's done.

Comment: Not sure how concurrently would handle that.  Must be another approach.  Still looking, thanks.